# Flex 4: Determining the index (not the selectedIndex) for a TabBar mouseOver

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have an application where I'm trying to update the String for a Label's text property, based on the tab which user has the mouse over. I've constructed a simple example displaying how I would process the eventHandler function if I *was* going to use the selectedIndex property, however it's the tab that has mouse focus, which may or may not be the selectedItem, that I'd like to reference and I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it.

So here is the example:

```
<s:Label 
    id="descriptionLabel"
    />
<s:TabBar 
    id="audioTB"
    dataProvider="{audioVS}"
    mouseOver="audioTB_mouseOverHandler(event)"
    rollOut="audioTB_rollOutHandler(event)"
    />
<mx:ViewStack 
    id="audioVS"
    >
    <!--- Menu1 -->
    <s:NavigatorContent
        id="audioNC1"
        label="Audio Menu 1"
        >
        <mx:DataGrid
            id="audioDG1"
            />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <!--- Menu2 -->
    <s:NavigatorContent
        id="audioNC2"
        label="Audio Menu 2"
        >
        <mx:DataGrid
            id="audioDG2"
            />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <!--- Menu3 -->
    <s:NavigatorContent
        id="audioNC3"
        label="Audio Menu 3"
        >
        <mx:DataGrid
            id="audioDG3"
            />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
~Benny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to solve this problem using custom event for tab bar buttons:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TabButtonEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const TAB_IS_OVER:String = "tabIsOver";

        private var _tabLabel:String;

        public function TabButtonEvent(type:String, tabLabel:String)
        {
            super(type,true,false);
            this._tabLabel = tabLabel;
        }

        public function get tabLabel():String
        {
            return _tabLabel;
        }

        public override function clone():Event
        {
            return new TabButtonEvent(type,tabLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should create your custom tab bar button skin. Good news are you can use inheritance:

```
package
{
import spark.skins.spark.TabBarButtonSkin;
import mx.events.StateChangeEvent;

public class TabBarButtonSkinExt extends TabBarButtonSkin
{
    public function TabBarButtonSkinExt()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE, currentStateChangeHandler);
    }

    private function currentStateChangeHandler(event:StateChangeEvent):void
    {
        if (event.newState.toLowerCase().indexOf("over") > -1)
        {
            dispatchEvent(new TabButtonEvent(TabButtonEvent.TAB_IS_OVER, hostComponent.label));
        }
    }
}
}
```

And include this button in tab bar skin (no inheritance, sorry):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- TabBarSkinExt.mxml -->
<s:Skin alpha.disabled="0.5" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009">
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.TabBar")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>
    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        /**
         *  @private
         *  Push the cornerRadius style to the item renderers.
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaleHeight:Number):void
        {
            const numElements:int = dataGroup.numElements;
            const cornerRadius:int = hostComponent.getStyle("cornerRadius");
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            {
                var elt:UIComponent = dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as UIComponent;
                if (elt)
                    elt.setStyle("cornerRadius", cornerRadius);
            }

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup -->
    <s:DataGroup height="100%" id="dataGroup" width="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:ButtonBarHorizontalLayout gap="-1" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="TabBarButtonSkinExt" />
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Skin>
```

And now your application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minHeight="600" minWidth="955" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function audioTB_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            descriptionLabel.text = " ";
        }

        protected function audioTB_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            audioTB.addEventListener(TabButtonEvent.TAB_IS_OVER, audioTB_tabIsOverHandler);
        }

        private function audioTB_tabIsOverHandler(event:TabButtonEvent):void
        {
            descriptionLabel.text = event.tabLabel;
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label id="descriptionLabel" />
    <s:TabBar dataProvider="{audioVS}" id="audioTB"
        rollOut="audioTB_rollOutHandler(event)" skinClass="TabBarSkinExt" initialize="audioTB_initializeHandler(event)" />
    <mx:ViewStack id="audioVS">
        <!--- Menu1 -->
        <s:NavigatorContent id="audioNC1" label="Audio Menu 1">
            <mx:DataGrid id="audioDG1" />
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <!--- Menu2 -->
        <s:NavigatorContent id="audioNC2" label="Audio Menu 2">
            <mx:DataGrid id="audioDG2" />
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <!--- Menu3 -->
        <s:NavigatorContent id="audioNC3" label="Audio Menu 3">
            <mx:DataGrid id="audioDG3" />
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is a great!!! I really appreciate it =] I was finally able to do what I was trying to do with this, Respect... ~Benny

Comment: I just had one question regarding this solution. I already have an mxml component skin, which I designed for the skinClass for the buttonBarButton itemRenderer which uses a ToggleButton as the host component. The skin has some additional styling which corresponds to with the up and selectedUp, selectedOver etc states. I'm not sure how to combine that information with the custom extended classes above. Any suggestions on approaching this would be appreciated. Thanks again, ~Benny

Comment: Just inherit skin from my sample not from `TabBarButtonSkin` but from your custom skin :) I think there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Indeed, no problems as you suspected. Thanks so much! =]